# Create angle gradient with RMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I want to create an angle gradient with RMagick. The final result should look something like the image below. I must be able to define the positions of the colors.

[image]

According to [this page of the ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/) it is possible with the below command.

```
convert -size 50x1000 gradient: -rotate 90 -alpha set \
          -virtual-pixel Transparent +distort Polar 49 +repage \
          -transverse  gradient_angle_masked.png
```

However, I am completely new to RMagick and by reading its documentation I have not been able to figure out how to translate their command to commands in RMagick.

Can anyone help me translate the command or point me in the right direction? Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to:

[**RMagick: Magick Command Options and Their Equivalent Methods**](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/optequiv.html)

You can find the corresponding RMagick methods/attributes of the command line arguments. The command you gave can be translated to the following Ruby code. However, to get the image you provided, you'll have to dig **more**.

```rb
require 'RMagick'

fill = Magick::GradientFill.new(0, 0, 0, 1000, '#FFF', '#000')
image = Magick::Image.new(50, 1000, fill)
image.rotate(90)
image.alpha(Magick::SetAlphaChannel)
image.virtual_pixel_method = Magick::TransparentVirtualPixelMethod
image = image.distort(Magick::PolarDistortion, [0]) do
  self.define('distort:Radius_Max', 49)
end
image.transpose
image = image.crop(0, 475, 50, 50, true)
image.write('test.png')
```

Some pages you might be interested:

- [RMagick User's Guide and Reference](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/)
- [How to Use RMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html)
- [Gradients of Colors](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#gradient)
- [Polar distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar) which specifies the arguments of the polar distortion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I'll take a look at the links you have posted. I'm trying to get it working using multiple colors. This has turned out to be an issue, though. I've tried using `Image.read` with a format and sparse colors, however, this has not worked. I might end up creating a new question for this.